# Passing by reference in PHP (function definition and variables)

Tags: php, reference

What's the difference between function &foo() and function foo(&$var) in PHP?

Example in code:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var){
   $var++;
}

function &bar(){
   $a= 5;
   return $a;
}

foo( bar() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is who wants to alter or read whose variable.
In the first example you want the outer variable to be changed by the function. In example two you want the outer world to change the inner variable. And you can get changed values from the different scope.

A better use case for the second version would be:

```
class example {
    public $test = 23;

    public function &exposeTest() {
        return $this->test;
    }
}

$example1 = new example;
$testref = &$example1->exposeTest();
$testref++;
echo($example1->test); // 24
$example1->test++;
echo($testref); // 25
```

So it is not really a difference besides design issues and without OOP may not matter any way.

Comment: Your code throws a fatal error around line 9 or 10. Specifically "$example1->exposeTest()++; ". But the explanation is good.

Comment: Edited it: Does it work now?
I mostly do dry coding and sometimes it does not work as I imagined.
But I found me a nice little online tester now.

Comment: Yeah. It works fine now. :). Does the online tester include debugging? I can't get xdebug to work with Sublime Text.